# To know about the code in mediawiki.?

Tags: ajax, mediawiki

The code is like

```
$searchInput.suggestions( {
        result: {
            render: renderFunction,
            select: function ( $input ) {
                $input.closest( 'form' ).submit();
            }
        },
        special: {
            render: specialRenderFunction,
            select: function ( $input ) {
                $input.closest( 'form' ).append(
                    $( '<input type="hidden" name="fulltext" value="1"/>' )
                );
                $input.closest( 'form' ).submit();
            }
        },
        $region: $searchRegion
    } )
```

in that ajax code i have not knowledge about render attribute. please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please visit below link may be helpful for you 
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser_functions